# C# selection of random numbers in range

Tags: c#, random, windows-phone

I want to produce a selection of random numbers in a range between 1 and 30, ideally this number will alter (to a max of +10) but will always have a range of 1 - 30. I want to be able to do this several times when needed. The numbers that I want to produce within the range will vary in numbers eg maybe I will want only 2 or 5 numbers.

I thought I should produce a static class and use the same random instance with a method that accepts an integer which indicated the total number of numbers I require within the range? Obviously the numbers should be no identical numbers returned from the method for each call. But if one method call produces the same numbers as a previous call then thats fine, but ideally they should differ.

I'm not sure how I would code this or if I'm completely wrong?

Sample code:

```
 public static class getMyNumbers
 {
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static int[] getThese(int i)
    {
        int[] wanted = new int[i];

        // a loop to generate the numbers???
        // this bit I'm not sure about the syntax
        // new to c#
        return wanted
    }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What you have described would work. You need to post your code so people can see if you've made a simple mistake.

Comment: See here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop putting the numbers into the array:

```
public static int[] getThese(int i)
{
    int[] wanted = new int[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        wanted[j] = random.Next(31);

    return wanted;
}
```

Note that the parameter to `random.Next()` is an exclusive upper range, so passing 31 will generate random numbers between 0 and 30.

As an aside, note that it's customary to use `n` for a count and `i` for a loop variable, so it would probably be better to name your variables thus:

```
public static int[] GetThese(int n)
{
    int[] result = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        result[i] = random.Next(31);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: OK simple, can I assume the returned numbers will all be different within this range?

Comment: @TripVoltage - The code as written does not prevent duplicates from being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Just because everybody loves Linq:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
public IEnumerable<int> GetRandomInts(int Amount, int Max = 30)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, Amount).Select(a => random.Next(Max)+1);
}
```

For no duplicates...

```
return Enumerable.Range(1, Max).OrderBy(a => random.Next()).Take(Amount);
```

Comment: Yes, numbers from 1 through max, which defaults to 30 unless you provide a different max.

Comment: Are you sure this does what you think it does?  I ran it and got many duplicates.  In fact, the Select will just select random numbers from 0 to 30 with no regard to what is in the Enumerable.Range.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I guess I didn't understand what the OP meant by unique. I thought he meant different output each time. If unique means no duplicates of course this doesn't return no duplicates, it's not how it was written. I guess I'll post an update for that new criteria.